# Как ускорить выполнение кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада

Пишу программу, которая решает следующую задачу:

Сколько существует 11-значных чисел, в записи которых встречаются все цифры?

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
count=0
for i in range(10**10, 10**11):
    cnt=0
    for j in range(0, 10):
        k=i
        while k>0:
            if k%10!=j:
                k=k//10
            else:
                cnt+=1
                break
    if cnt==10:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Однако такой код будет выполняться слишком долго. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4):

В развитие логического подхода S.H.:

Удвоенная цифра может стоять на первом месте, 9 вариантов, тогда остаётся десять мест для десяти цифр, и подобных комбинаций `9*10!`

Пусть теперь на первом месте стоит одиночная цифра `a`, 9 вариантов. Применим хитрость - расставим 10 **разных** цифр на оставшиеся 10 мест - это 10! перестановок, потом заменим внутри этих перестановок уже имеющуюся первую цифру `a` на 9 возможных замен, получается 9*10!*9, и разделим пополам, потому что не можем различить две одинаковые цифры `9*10!*9/2`

Вместе получается

```
9*10! + 9*10!*9/2 = 10! * (18 + 81)/2 = 10!*99/2 = 179 625 600
```

Для случаев, когда система основания N не равна 10, общая формула

```
n! * (n-1)*(n+1) / 2 =  (n+1)!*(n-1)/2
```

например, для n=2 легко проверить результат 3 `(0b100,0b101,0b110)`, для n=3 результат 24  и т.д.

Comment: Фантастика! я зашел, чтобы отредактировать свой ответ, и обнаружил, что всё уже сделано! спасибо! отметил плюсиком!

Answer (score 3):

Подход должен быть немного другим.

в 11 значном числе, в котором должны встречаться все 10 цифр, две цифры должны повторяться.

Тогда задача сводится к тому, сколько есть 11 значных чисел, в записи которых есть две одинаковые цифры.

Такое число характеризуется тремя независимыми параметрами:

1. какая цифра повторяется (10 вариантов)
2. где она встречается в числе первый раз (11 вариантов)
3. где она встречается второй раз (10 вариантов)

Таким образом, это 10 * 11 * 10.

Это кол-во надо разделить на два (это понятно?) и выкинуть те варианты, когда впереди один или два ведущих нуля.

Как то так :-)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Вообще-то, эта задача предлагалась на олимпиаде по математике, а не по информатике. Поэтому подразумевалось, что участники олимпиады не станут решать эту задачу программно. Мне же хотелось именно программно решить, так как я пытаюсь научиться программировать. Кстати, ответ на эту задачу совсем другой: (9 × 9! × 9 × 11 + 9 × 9! × 10) : 2.

Comment: интересно. Да, я согласен, я не всё учел в своём совете. попробую откорректировать...

Comment: @MBo - да, я уже понял, пытаюсь написать с учетом перестановок. задача не выглядит слишком сложной :-)

Answer (score 3):

Надеюсь, я правильно всё сообразил. За минуту примерно посчиталось:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from itertools import permutations

n = 11
count=0
items = list(range(10))
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    for x in permutations(items + [i], n):
        if x[0] == 0:
            continue
        count += 1
print(count//2)
```

Вывод:

```
179625600
```

- берём список из 10 разных цифр
- добавляем к нему по очереди разные цифры
- считаем все возможные комбинации из этих 11 цифр
- но отбрасываем из них те, которые начинаются на 0 (это не будут числа с длиной 11)
- делим результат на 2 (потому что две перебираемые цифры в каждом из чисел взаимозаменяемы и эти числа не отличимы друг от друга)

Ну и "однострочник" (если не считать строку с подключением библиотеки):

```
from itertools import permutations

print(sum(x[0] != 0 for i in range(10) for x in permutations(list(range(10)) + [i], 11)) // 2)
```

Comment: А почему у Вас ответ 359251200, а не 177992640?

Comment: @ЯнАльбертовичДененберг Не знаю. Может я где-то ошибся? Надо разбираться :)

Comment: @ЯнАльбертовичДененберг Разделил на 2 (дошло, почему надо делить), ответ стал ближе, но всё-равно почему-то не такой.

Comment: 177992640 - неверно.

Comment: @MBo А какое верное? Чтоб я не мучился дальше, если вдруг уже правильно )

Comment: @CrazyElf   179 625 600

Comment: А, так у вас оно и получается, сразу не углядел вывода.

Comment: @MBo Сначала там было другое, я сначала не догадался, почему писали, что нужно делить на 2 )  И вывод `tqdm` только мешает, уберу его

Answer (score 2):

Перебор такого количества чисел за разумное время на сделать, так что эту проблему не решить. Чуток ускорить можно, например, так

```
for i in range(10**10, 10**11):
    cnt=0
    print(i)
    s = set(str(i))
    if len(s)==10:
        count+=1
```

Ну и начинать надо не с 10¹⁰, а с минимального 11-значного числа, в котором есть все 10 цифр. Заканчивать, соответственно, максимальным.

Но это все как экономия на трамвайном билете, когда направляешься в автосалон пешком, чтобы купить автомобиль.

Comment: Я ради интереса запустил просто сам `range` + `tqdm` вообще без логики внутри, только с `pass`, так он вообще не двигается, там какое-то большое `ETA` получается, порядка 7 часов. А если ещё логику внутрь добавить... )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну да, сократит оптимизация выполнение с двух лет до года и 359 дней (наугад), разницы все равно никакой :)